# How to do Textures/Material for a Concrete Floor?

Tags: texturing, materials, texture-baking, texture-painting

I've been puzzling over how to create a believable concrete floor, something about 1800 square feet like the floor of a warehouse/factory with scuffed lines of paint, worn areas and maybe even a frost crack or three.

**More info:** this is for an animation environment with characters who are about two feet in height, so the floor will be quite visible in a lot of the shots. I'm assuming the low-rez approach used for games will be too fuzzy looking, but I'm also hoping to keep render times down while maximizing detail as much as possible.

**What I Know/Have Tried:** I know image textures end up more believable than procedural textures, but in my attempts with 1024-square image textures a repeated pattern really stands out, taking away from the effect I'm looking for. But using large image textures sounds like a recipe for crashing Cycles when it inevitably runs out of RAM.

So what's the best, GPU RAM-friendly way to create this type of material/texture?

Comment: I recommend use if this [free texture](https://www.poliigon.com/texture/1384) from poliigon(The texture is actually plaster, but looks like concrete). Adding the bump maps which it comes with will also really help convince the viewer it is actual concrete. If you want to pay money poliigon is a great place to get high quality textures, but only has a few free textures. Hope this helps 

Comment: a cool way to break up texture repetition is the use of vertex colors, detail textures and UV warping

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Patrick. Still looking for a more detailed reply, though.

Comment: I'll look into those. I'm assuming there are tutorials covering these?

Comment: I'm beginning to believe this is impossible. No concrete (forgive the pun) suggestions and I've been Googling for days with no results. The closest I've come was a vague outline of a method (read: not very helpful) from 2012 or so and now I can't find it again.

Comment: I'd put a bounty on this, but I've got so little reputation, I'd hate to give it up for this. (sigh)